# Java-Prolog: How to pass arguments to arity 2 query?

Tags: java, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I am a beginner level on both Prolog and Java. I am trying to link my Prolog program with Java. I found how to do so [here](http://www.tobias-weigl.de/blog/jpl-prolog-for-java/). But I have no idea how to pass the arguments to Prolog query with arity 2. This is a piece of my prolog program:

```
male(Jack).
male(John).
female(Jill).
couple(Jack,Jill).
parent(Jack,John).
parent(Jill,John).
```

And this is from my Java:

```
Query q1 = new Query("female", new Term[] {new Atom("Jill")});
System.out.println("Is Jill female? " + q1.hasSolution());
```

This results: "Is Jill female? **true**"

```
Query q2 = new Query(new Compound("male", new Term[] {new Variable("X")}));

        int i=0;
        while(q2.hasMoreSolutions()){
            i++;
            System.out.print(i + ") " +q2.nextSolution().get("X"));
        }
```

This results: "1) Jack 2) John"

But I don't know how to run the queries with arity 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
new Query("parent", new Term[] {new Atom("Jill"),new Atom("John")});
```

`new Term[]` means you initialize an *array*, evidently, you can thus call it with multiple atoms.

See [this documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/java_api/getting_started.html) under the *Querying the Database* section.

Comment: Yippee! Thx a lot! ^^